# Dynamically maintain virtual pages URL without create pages from admin

Tags: wordpress

I created a page named **UserName** its URL is `http://my_site/username/`. On this page I am showing three links, and each link behaves as **meta info** for **UserName**.

Let's suppose:

If **UserName** contains info about User then the three links are:

1. About Me
2. Images
3. Videos

and links contains href like:

1. `http://my_site/username/about_me`
2. `http://my_site/username/images`
3. `http://my_site/username/videos`

now I create three general files like:

1. about_me.php
2. images.php
3. videos.php

and want to include these file by checking the URL, but I don't know how.

I did it without adding new page from wp-admin because there will be so many **UserName** pages but they all have same three links and will show the info about respective **user**.

And if I prefer to create **About Me** child page whose parent will be the **UserName** page then admin will need to create **3*(n UserName)** pages where **n** least value is **100** and could be **1000s**

But when I click any link WP says

> Page Not Found
>
> This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?

I select `Custom Structure` from **Settings** and I have no more idea about WP permalinks.

> You may call I need to create **Virtual** pages for all users.

If it is not possible then is it possible that while adding new **UserName** page then on published three pages (**About Me**, **Images** & **Videos**) will automatically with parent page newly **UserName** page and with a defined **Page Template**. If it is possible then how?

Answer (score 1):

Wow I got an idea, implement & hurray it worked.

In `wp-admin/includes/post.php` I add my script in `function edit_post( $post_data = null )`

First I checked if post not already exists then run my script which is:

```
$post = array(
          'comment_status' => 'closed',
          'ping_status'    => 'closed',
          'post_author'    => $current_user_id,
          'post_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_date_gmt'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
          'post_name'      => 'Image',
          'post_parent'    => $post_parent,
          'post_status'    => 'publish',
          'post_title'     => 'Image',
          'post_type'      => 'page'
        );
        // Insert in to WP wp_posts table
        $this_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error ); 
        // Insert in to wp_postmeta table
        $meta_id = update_post_meta($this_post_id , '_wp_page_template', 'page-three-columns.php');
```